# updating records in BIG table without using 'in' statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

The table is a big table,millions of records.

Table 1 has three column

An ID, column X and column Y. Currently i am using an "in" statement which is slow; especially so in a BIG table. I am looking to increase the performance of this update statement without using the in statement. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
    Update [Table1] set Column_X='Delete' where Column_Y in(    
    select distinct (Column_Y) from [Table1]  where Column_X='Delete'
    )

   result before running script
   Table 1

   ID     Column X    Column Y      
   1      Delete      CAT           
   2      x1          CAT           
   3      x1          CAT        
   4      x1          COW           
   5      x1          COW     
   6      x2          Moon           
   7      Delete      Chicken         


   Intended result after running script
   Table 1

   ID     Column X    Column Y      
   1      Delete      CAT           
   2      Delete      CAT           
   3      Delete      CAT        
   4      x1          COW           
   5      x1          COW     
   6      x2          Moon           
   7      Delete      Chicken
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same table more than once in the FROM clause, so something like:

```
update Table1
   set Column_X = 'Delete'
  from Table1 a, Table1 b
 where a.Column_Y = b.Column_Y
   and b.Column_X = 'Delete'
```

The update affects the first instance of Table1, i.e. "a".

Answer (score 1):

you can use an exists clause on this.

```
Update [Table1] set Column_X='Delete' from [Table1] t1where exists(
select t2.Column_Y
from [Table1] t2
where t2.Column_X = 'Delete'
and t2.Column_Y = t1.Column_Y)
```

It should get a bit faster than "in" clause.

P.S.: never use "in" since it does a full table scan. "Exists" clause should fit on almost all cases.